# date inserted in wrong format in db after update using PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am using [date time picker](http://www.rainforestnet.com/datetimepicker/datetimepicker-demo9.htm) to get date and have one datetime type field in db which I am trying to update.

Following jquery code makes a request to `edit.php`

```
var nextdate=  $("#"+date).attr('value');
$('#div').load('edit.php?date='+nextdate);
```

In edit.php, I'm getting the correct date `2013-04-18 18:18:18`

But in database it is inserted in this format: `2013-04-18 00:00:00`, where the actual date is `2013-04-18 18:18:18`

I've also tried

```
echo $d =$_GET['date'];
echo $date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($d));
```

**Note:** update query directly on db is working fine.

PHP code is

```
update call_track  set  next_call_time='$date'   where  id='$id'
```

and the database query is

```
update call_track set next_call_time='2013-04-18 18:18:18' where id='118'
```

why this is not working with PHP code.

this is the code 
on update.php

```
function leaveChanger(id)
{
    var tpid ='display_'+id;
    var date='date_'+id;
    var nextdate=  $("#"+date).attr('value');

    $('#'+tpid).load('edit.php?id='+id+'&date='+nextdate);


}
</script>
<input type='button' name='' id='' value='Change'  class='button green' Onclick='leaveChanger(118);return false;'/> <div id='dispaly_$id' style='color:red;'></div> 
<input type='Text' value='$date' id='date_118' maxlength='25' size='19'/>
<img src='images2/cal.gif' onclick=\"javascript:NewCssCal ('date_118','yyyyMMdd','arrow',true,'24',true)\"/> <div id='display_118'></div>
```

edit.php

```
include("../../dashboard/Includes/db_connect.php");
 echo $id=$_GET['id']; 

echo $d =$_GET['date'];
echo $date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($d)); 

echo $query="update  call_track set next_call_time='$date' where id='$id'";

if(mysql_query($query))
echo "Updated"; 
else
echo "Not Updated";
```

Comment: Could you please provide the full code (php) ?

Comment: what is the output of `echo $d;` and `echo $date;`?

Comment: is it possible that the column " next_call_time" in the DB is accidentally a DATE column and not DATETIME?

Comment: @nvanesch "update query directly on db is working fine" so I doubt it.

Comment: @daiscog  2013-04-18 18:18:18     2013-04-18 18:18:18

Comment: Do you have any error in console ? (Like a 500...)

Comment: Can you post the PHP code used to build and send the SQL query?

Comment: you can use mysql_error() to get error.Chances are mismatch type of values.

//do :
echo "update call_track set next_call_time='$date' where id='$id'";
//now run printed query in DB directly.

Comment: @SusheelMishra there is no error printed. and echoed query and ested on db directly, its working perfect.

Comment: can u print echoed query.If no error is coming then plese check your DB setting.Possibly.

Comment: @jaya post your complete edit.php code, there might be something related to it that you're overlooking.

Comment: @Ejay Updated code also

Comment: You are not defining your `$id` variable but a `$pid` variable...

Comment: waht is the datatype of next_call_time field?

Comment: @SupritiPanda  next_call_time datetime

Comment: @jaya you should put `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` on top of your page and make sure that you're not getting any errors

Comment: @Ejay no errors printed

Comment: `echo $query="update  call_track  next_call_time='$date' where id='$id'";` this query is missing `SET`.

Comment: If none of those answers is the solution, are you sure of your database configuration in `db_connect.php` ? By the way, how can you mistype by copy/pasting ?

Comment: Since this appears to be a typo problem, voting to close as Too Localised. Pleased it's been fixed, though!

Comment: @Brewal, yes it is. i am getting updated message also. but after update have seen values from db, it is only with 00:00:00

Comment: Try with this : `$date=strtotime($d);`. Just curious...

Comment: @jaya To correct typos in your code, IMO, you should not edit your code in its place but should put a new "Update" section in your question for each update you make and let the relevant fellows know. This way the comments will remain relevant and we'll know how many times you've edited the question since it was posted.

Comment: @Brewal it was only 1366784603

Comment: Yes but did it make it work ? I'm out of idea. By the way, `mysql_query` is not anymore recommended as it is deprecated : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-query.php. You could try it with PDO...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all of you. Problem was solved by placing

```
    var nextdate=  $("#"+date).attr('value');
    var date =encodeURIComponent(nextdate);

    $('#'+tpid).load('edit.php?id='+id+'&date='+date);
```

> encodeURIComponent was solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are difining `$pid` variable, not `$id`. Replace this line :

`$query="update  call_track  next_call_time='$date' where id='$id'";`

by this one :

`$query="update  call_track  next_call_time='$date' where id='$pid'";`

Next time, try to var_dump() the entire query : `var_dump($query);`
You will find that the generated query was :

`update  call_track set next_call_time='2013-04-18 18:18:18' where id=''`

This affects 0 rows as there is no record matching an empty id.

Comment: Well, give it the name you want :)